# How to work that JavaScript_button in mustache template?

Tags: javascript, mustache

```
{{#stocks}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{client}}</td>
                <td>{{productName}}</td>
                <td>{{color}}</td>
                <td>{{size}}</td>
                <td>{{amount}}</td>
                <td>
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="addAmount" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div style="display:none" class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="id" class="form-control" value="{{id}}" style="display:none">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="btn-addAmount">add</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
    {{/stocks}}
```

this is my web_server project mustache template part

```
var addAmount = {
init: function () {
    var _this = this;
    $('#btn-addAmount').on('click', function () {
        _this.addAmount();
    })
},

addAmount: function () {
    var data = {
        id: $('#id').val(),
        addAmount: $('#addAmount').val()
    }
    if(!data.addAmount) {
        alert("input amount");
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/api/v1/addAmount',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset = utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).done(function() {
            window.location.href = "/users/stock";
        }).fail(function (error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    }
}
};
```

addAmount.init();

this is javascript button in my web_server project mustache template

When I run this code at this situation, only the first items button works. I want to make other buttons work too. Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: The question seems to be missing some important information but from what I can see it seems like you have an array of items which all have a button with the id `btn-addAmount`. This is not possible since the id has to be **unique** for an element. You can change this to a class  run the `addAmount` function directly from the button element.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the late thanks.